# Invalid syntax on importing nltk in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax, syntax-error, nltk

when I executed the below code in python 2.7 CLI

```
import nltk
```

it is showing the following error

```
SyntaxError:Invalid Syntax

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/nani/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
from nltk.collocations import *
File "/home/nani/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/collocations.py", line 35, in <module>
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
File "/home/nani/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/probability.py", line 333
print("%*s" % (width, samples[i]), end=" ")                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to fix this?

Comment: NLTK does not support Python 2.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

nltk dropped support to Python2, Try to use older versions of nltk in which it supports python 2 and I found out that nltk 3.0 version supports python 2 [edited - Thanks to [user2357112 supports Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112-supports-monica)
]

So, Try to download and install previous versions of nltk with the command

```
pip install nltk==3.0
```

You can change the version number which is 3.0 in the above mentioned case and can install suitable version whichever you feels working.

It worked for me.If anyone facing same problem can try above mentioned method.

Comment: This is not a bug and will not be "fixed" in upcoming versions. NLTK has dropped support for Python 2.

Answer (score 2):

The code is using the `print` function, which in Python 2.7 has to be enabled with

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

However, this has to appear in the module being imported, not the code importing the module. `nltk` appears to assume it will be imported by a Python 3 interpreter.

Comment: Can you tell me in which module do I need to add this line as there are many sub folders and .py and .pyc codes are there in nltk module?

Comment: You would have to put it in every module that uses a `print` function. There may be other things in each module that a Python 2 interpreter cannot use, though.

Comment: If supporting Python 2 could have been achieved by adding a couple of future imports, then I'm sure the `nltk` team would have done it. But they have moved on. I don't think that revisiting that decision is something a beginner should attempt.