# Python nlkt not working on Mac - neither python nor python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, nltk

I would like to use nltk with Python on my MacOS Catalina. I have installed python with version 2.7.16 in /usr/bin/python and python3 with version 3.8.5. in /usr/local/bin/python3. I have also installed nltk with pip (/usr/local/bin/pip) and also pip3 (/usr/local/bin/pip3). Both with the sudo before the install command. I have nltk libraries in the following directories

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/
/Users/xyz/Library/Python/3.8//lib/python/site-packages/nltk
```

When trying "import nltk" in python I get

```
>>> import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
    from nltk.collocations import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/collocations.py", line 35, in <module>
    from nltk.probability import FreqDist
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/probability.py", line 333
    print("%*s" % (width, samples[i]), end=" ")
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and in python3 I get

```
>>> import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'
```

How can I use nltk? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Something with your `$PATH` env is not right... I would install python with `pyenv` as it is much easier to manage multiple python versions on your computer with this tool:
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#homebrew-on-macos

Comment: Your first example is Python 2 not Python3 and you are getting the error because you are importing the Python 3 version of `nltk` in Python 2. It looks like you have installed the Python 3 version in Python 2, and have not successfully installed it in Python 3 at all. As a beginner you should stick to Python 3 *only*.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61560956/invalid-syntax-when-i-imported-nltk-in-python-2-7/61575357#61575357'

Comment: Sorry BoarGules. I typed python3 but meant python. I corrected the post.

Comment: I installed pyenv (there I installed the latest python verion and set global to this version). I also reinstalled nltk via pip3. Now the library is available via python3. Thank you!